# Align text with a curve

Tags: bezier-curves, text-object

Simple file with one circle and one text object.
When I try to associate the text with the circle under F button there is no circle on the list.
[image: screenshot]

Is this a bug?

Blender file:
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31793

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Nope, it has to be a Curve object. BezierCircle works, Mesh does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has to be a Curve object. BezierCircle e.g. works, while a mesh circle does not. If you add a BezierCircle:

[image]

It will show up and work as intended:

[image]